# React boostrap Form file design just text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to make file choose, just text like choose file and open file choose area open, I use react boostrap how can I do that below is my code now is choose file button and I don't want this and I searching google and I don't found solution

```
<Form.Group>
  <Form.File onChange={onChangeFile} id="choseFile" isInvalid={true} />
</Form.Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code maybe this is what you want

```
<Form.Group>
  <Form.File onChange={onChangeFile} id="choseFile" isInvalid={true} label="chose a file" custom/>
</Form.Group>
```

Comment: Didn't solve my problem title is not prop From.File